# ¿Cómo conectar una base de datos MongoDB a Angular?

Tags: angular, base-de-datos, mongodb

Estoy aprendiendo Angular y para ello, estoy desarrollando una red social. He creado los distintos componentes y he establecido las rutas correspondientes. Sin embargo, he llegado a un punto clave en el que llevo tiempo atascado: la conexión a la base de datos. La base de datos MongoDB la he creado utilizando el programa Robo3T. El problema es que no sé cómo conectar la base de datos con el proyecto de Angular. No sé si tendría que crear un servicio a parte o si necesito alguna herramienta extra aparte de Angular. He buscado información al respecto y he encontrado este código en muchas webs:

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose");

   mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/nombreBBDD", {
     useNewUrlParser:true,
     useUnifiedTopology: true
   })
    .then(()=>{
      console.log("Conexión correcta");
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);
    })
```

El problema es que no sé dónde exactamente debería ir ese código. He probado tanto en un componente como en un servicio y siempre recibo el error "mongoose.connect is not a function", pese a que tengo mongoose instalado, ya que en el archivo package.json aparece "mongoose:^6.2.10".
Llevo un tiempo atascado en esta parte y si alguien pudiera ayudarme lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: La conexión a la base de datos se hace desde el lado backend y no desde frontend (Angular). Por lo cual, necesitas un servidor de back que reciba las peticiones de tu aplicación Angular y realice las llamadas a la base de datos. Dicho servidor puede estar programado en cualquier lenguaje: PHP, Java, Javascript, C#, Python, etc.

Comment: Ya instalaste el paquete de casualidad? Y ese código de la conexión va en el archivo del servidor de la aplicación

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/functions/

Encontré esto que tal vez te sirva en: https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/angular
Serverless architecture is a software design pattern which incorporates third-party cloud platforms to manage server-side code.

Serverless architecture provides an alternative to the traditional client-server model. Instead of implementing and hosting your own server, you upload your server-side logic to a “serverless” platform in the cloud. There’s still a server where your code is hosted, but you’re delegating its management to the serverless platform.

Function-as-a-Service (FaaS) is one category of serverless architecture. With FaaS, you’re deploying functions to the serverless platform and then calling these functions from your client application.

For example, instead of building a Node.js server, you can abstract away the communication with your MongoDB database by placing it in MongoDB Atlas Functions. Then, you can call these from your Angular application.

These functions are the server-side logic in your application architecture. With this approach, you’re saving the time and effort of building and maintaining a server.

Comment: tal vez sea mejor sí traduces lo que haz puesto en la respuesta

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: No olvides que estamos en [es.so]: las preguntas y sus respuestas deben ir en el idioma oficial del sitio. Por cierto, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [answer].